# Retrieving Owner.Name from List of objects

Tags: soql, query

I am trying to retrieve the following fields Owner.Name, Name, Id from ActionPlanTemplate object and returning a list. However, when the list is returned, I do not get Owner.Name in the ActionPlanTemplate object.

How can I get the Owner.Name in the ActionPlanTemplate list for each object?

When I enter the same query in Query Editor, I get the correct results.

```
String test = 'SELECT Owner.Name, Name, Id from ActionPlanTemplate';

List<ActionPlanTemplate> apt = database.query(test);

System.debug(apt);
```

This returns:

> (ActionPlanTemplate:{OwnerId=0031W000019AA3qWBF, Name=APT Test, Id=0WS5E0000000044WAA}, ...

EDIT:
After reading the recommended solutions, Yes Owner.Name can be called when I refer to it directly as object.Owner.Name, however I am trying to display this component as a value in my lightning data table column.

```
component.set('v.APcolumns', [
        {label: 'Action Plan Template Name', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url', typeAttributes:{ label: { fieldName: 'Name'} }, target:'_blank', sortable: 'true'},
        {label: 'Template Owner', fieldName: 'Owner.Name', type: 'text'}
    ]);
```

The Action Plan Template name shows up, but not the Owner.Name

Comment: `System.debug()` is deceiving you. See the answers on the linked question for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Specific to your question, you can debug the value directly as follows:

```
for (ActionPlanTemplate record : apt)
{
    system.debug(record.Owner.Name);
}
```